# Roo Annotation for Composite Id

Tags: java, jpa, spring-roo

If I have a class entity having more than 1 PK, should I use identifier class or embeddable class (or is it the same)?

I am having problems dealing with the `@RooJavaBean` class with more than 1 `@Id`:

```
@RooJavaBean
// other Roo Entity Annotation
class EntityTable {

    @Id @Column(name="fk_entity_sub_one")
    private Integer fkPkOne;

    @Id @Column(name="fk_entity_sub_one")
    private Integer fkPkTwo;
}
```

**Note:** I used primitive data-type object instead of the entity object because I don't need to a return map. (Did I have the right idea to save memory upon entity loading?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this commands:

```
   entity jpa --class ~.domain.EntityTable --identifierType ~.domain.EntityTablePk --entityName EntityTable --identifierField myPk --table TABLE
   field number --fieldName fkPkOne --type java.lang.Integer --column fk_entity_sub_one --class ~.domain.EntityTablePk
   field number --fieldName fkPkTwo --type java.lang.Integer --column fk_entity_sub_two --class ~.domain.EntityTablePk
```

And look at [JPA Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cmp30cfg001.htm)

Comment: Thanks. I have the same output when I try to do `database reverse engineer`. Yet I am having a problem on accessing the identifier class. I know it's out of the concept of this thread yet I have already created one for it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754924/accessing-roo-identifier)