# Accessing Roo Identifier

Tags: jpa, spring-roo, composite-key, composite-primary-key

I have this entity class having more than one primary key (`@Id`) which resulted me to use `@RooJpaActiveRecord(identifierType = '<IdentifierClass.class>')` and `@RooIdentifier(dbManaged=true)`. Yet I am having a problem on accessing `Identifier.class` from the entity class itself.

My questions is how can I access `Identifier` in the entity class without, at most, removing the `@RooJpaActiveRecord(identifierType = '<Identifier.class>')` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roo will generate a property *id* on your entity. This property is declared on MyEntity_Roo_Jpa_Entity.aj file (this includes a getter/setter). So, you simple use:

```
    MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
    myEntity.setId(new Identifier());
    myEntity.getId().setPk1(value1);
    // ....
    // ....
    myEntity.getId().setPkn(valuen);
```